# Is it possible to take a product of measures defined on a common measure space?

Tags: measure-theory

This is not a question about "product measures" in the usual sense of the phrase. Here's what I'm interested in: is there a way of combining measures $\nu$ and $\nu'$ on a common measure space to obtain a new measure $\nu \nu'$, in a way that mimics pointwise products of functions? So in particular, I'd like this notion to interact nicely with Radon-Nikodym derivatives, meaning:
$$\frac{d\nu\nu'}{d\mu} = \frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\frac{d\nu'}{d\mu}$$

I suppose this is trivial whenever both Radon-Nikodym derivatives exist, so I guess my question is really whether or not we can do this in cases where they don't exist.

Comment: Related on MO: [Opinions on the Multiplication of Measures](http://mathoverflow.net/q/100469/90906).

Comment: @DominiqueR.F., thanks, that looks like it answers my question.

Comment: @goblin you have a reference on when the derivatives do exits?